# AppFabric Regions and Local Cache

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

(1) I'm wondering if I use Regions in my AppFabric Caching is it possible for the Regions to exist on the local cache?  Or do regions only exist on the cluster?

(2) As a separate question how can I tell if my data is coming from the Cluster or from my local cache?  Is there some kind of AppFabric tool that I can use to analyse where the data is coming from?

I am using configuration in code to set up my local cache properties to put my items in to local cache like so

```
localCacheConfig = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties(10000, localTimeout, DataCacheLocalCacheInvalidationPolicy.TimeoutBased);

// Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration.
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
factoryConfig.Servers = servers;
factoryConfig.LocalCacheProperties = localCacheConfig;

//code to put items in cache....etc
```

Do I need to do anything special on the 'Get' or is it smart enough to get it from local cache if it exists there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Region is a logical concept in AppFabric. It will allow you to query items by tag, but items will be stored in only one host (limited distribution and high availability too).

Local cache is not bound to region. it's just a local copy of your latest call to the cache cluster.
Local cache is enabled on client side, meaning that you can avoid it if you want.

The lifetime of an object in the local cache is dependent on several factors, such as the maximum number of objects in the local cache and the invalidation policy (timeout or notification).

You cannot know is data is coming from local cache or distributed cache. That's why local cache is recommended for reference data.

Answer (score 1):

1.Regions do not exist in local cache, regions are specific to cache cluster only.

2.You can get statistics of a particular named cache by executing the below command in Appfabric powershell console,

```
get-cachestatistics <CacheName>
```

It gives you a result set which has **ReadRequestCount**, if a request goes to local cache this count will not increase for the particular request.

By this way you can check the local cache working.

Answer (score 0):

Regions can't exist in a local cache, they only exist inside a cache on the cluster.

Because local cache is optional, client code should be completely agnostic about whether a cached item is coming from the cluster or from the local cache. To enable that, when a requested item is in the local cache it will be returned from there (avoiding a cross-server call to the cluster).

Comment: Sure - but how can I check that it is in fact working correctly and coming from the local cache?

Comment: Also, in regard to the Regions I'm led to believe that if we dont specify a Region then items go into a Default Region.  If they go into a Default Region then how is it possible for them to exist in local cache if Regions cant exist on local cache?

Comment: What happens if I add my items to a Region, that Region exists on distributed cache.  Do the individual items still exist on local cache without a region?